# Unable to run .NET 5.0 service as a different user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

**Background:**

I am trying to get an ASP.NET 5.0 service to run as a different user (by `shift`+`right click` and selecting *Run as different user*) because of DCOM but I am unable to do so and simply receive the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Process has exited, so the requested information is not available.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_SessionId()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices.WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServiceLifetimeHostBuilderExtensions.UseWindowsService(IHostBuilder hostBuilder, Action`1 configure)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServiceLifetimeHostBuilderExtensions.UseWindowsService(IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
   at Historian.Service.Program.CreateHostBuilder(String[] args) in ..\Program.cs:line 31
   at Historian.Service.Program.Main(String[] args) in ..\Program.cs:line 27
```

Below is my basic service code.

```cs
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();//This is "Line 27"
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices(services =>//This is "Line 31"
                {
                    services.AddLogging(logging => logging.AddConsole().AddDebug());                  
                })
                .ConfigureWebHost(config =>
                {
                    config.UseKestrel((builderContext, options) =>
                    {
                        options.Configure(builderContext.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"));
                    })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .UseWindowsService();
    }
```

And here is my `Startup` code:

```cs
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

            services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Level = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Fastest;
            });

            services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
            {
                options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
                options.EnableForHttps = true;
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyService", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Historian.Collector.Service v1"));
            }

            app.UseResponseCompression();

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();            

            //app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

**Additional Info:**

When running the service via `Services` and adding the correct user credentials through the `Logon` option within `Properties`, the service also does not work. The user is also on a different domain.

**Current Workaround:**

I am able to get an instance of the service working by opening a `cmd` window as a different user (by `shift`+`right click` and selecting *Run as different user*) and then opening the service from the `cmd` window.

**My Question:**

Why does my service not run as a different user? Are there any code based solutions that I may implement?

## UPDATE

Through testing I have been able to isolate the issue as follows:

1. Create a new local user account in windows
2. Give the created user account full control of the containing debug folder (right click > properties > security > edit > add new user > assign "Full Control" > save)
3. Give the created user account "Logon As Service" rights (Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy > Dropdown "Local Policies" > Double Click "User Rights Assignment" > Double Click "Logon as a service" > Add your created user account > OK)
4. Shift + Right Click > Run as different user on the test.exe console app (see code below)
5. Enter local user name and password and run
6. Attach to the process from Visual Studio (`Console.ReadLine();` gives you time to attach to process)
7. Step through code and see error on "Line where error occurs"

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //This is here so that one can attach to the process
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");  
        Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        IHostBuilder hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

        hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
        });

        try
        {
            hostBuilder.UseWindowsService();//Line where error occurs
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        return hostBuilder;

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried this:
Task Manager > Services (right-click on the service) >  Open Sevices (right-click on the service) > Properties > Logon > This Account

Comment: Hi @Nemavhidi, I have tried this and had stated it under the Additional Info heading. Sorry if this was not clear, I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Check the event log for more information (system and application). The error you're getting now is a very generic one that just says the process is gone; the service control manager and/or runtime may log more.

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert, there was nothing different in the Event Viewer. Please see my update for how to reproduce the bug.